# Which Notation Makes The Most Sense?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

I want the right notation for saying, "The infinite unions from $k=-\infty$ to $\infty$ of set $\left\{\left.\frac{2m+1}{2^k(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, whose elements are between $[a,b]$, equals the set of rational numbers, whose elements are between $[a,b]$.

Which notation makes the most sense

a. $\bigcup\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{\left.\frac{2m+1}{2^k(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[a,b]=\left\{\left.\frac{m}{n}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[a,b]$

b.  $\bigcup\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}[a,b]\cap\left\{\left.\frac{2m+1}{2^k(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=[a,b]\cap\left\{\left.\frac{m}{n}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$

c. $\bigcup\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left\{\left.\frac{2m+1}{2^k(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\in[a,b]=\left\{\left.\frac{m}{n}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\in[a,b]$

Or is there a better notation?

Comment: Option c makes no sense at all.  But I think you need to give a little more context.  It's very unclear to me why you write $m,n$ separately from $k$ even though all three appear to be universally quantified integers.

Comment: Also, $\{\frac{m}{n}\mid m,n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is a fairly awkward way to describe the rationals, since you aren't restricting $n \ne 0$.  Why not just use $\mathbb Q$ for the rationals?

Comment: Shorter: $\;\bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left\{\,\left.\frac{2m+1}{2^k(2n+1)}\in [a,b] \;\right|\;m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\,\right\} = [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @ErickWong If I set k has all values set in the infinite union then why should we set k, inside the set, to Z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on an equation, I would recommend the much more succulent

$$\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left\{\frac{m}{n}2^k\in[a,b]:m,n\text{ are odd}\right\}=[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$$

You have notions like "odd numbers" and "rational numbers" and using them lets you greatly simplify the expression involved. You can also get rid of a parameter by making it the ratio of an even and an odd number, if that is okay in your context. I changed the exponent of the $2$ from $-k$ to $k$ because it looks more aesthetically pleasing to me. It doesn't matter which way you do it (probably, again depending on context) because that just reverses the order of the union.

Depending on context, I might advise you to skip the formalism all together because it's still moderately cumbersome and more time consuming to read than the sentence "every rational number between $a$ and $b$ can be expressed as the ratio of an odd and an even number."